# Where can I find an SA302 form online?

Tags: taxes, hmrc

I have logged into my Self Assessment Portal for HMRC but can't seem to find where to print off an SA302 from.

I have already spent 45 min on the phone to HMRC and they are sending me them out in the post, but I need them as soon as possible for a mortgage application.

Could someone point me in the right direction?  I have Googled this a fair bit, but a lot of the guides online are for the old style layout of the site, and every time I go in it is in the new gov.uk beta format.

Comment: As I see it, I'm not sure if we should be a HMRC support channel on Freelancing StackExchange. It doesn't really make sense. It could be okay for help in the short term, but it should be discussed on meta.

Comment: I had no clue what HMRC even was until I Googled it.  Explaining that it's a UK or European entity would go a long way :)

Comment: @Scott I wrote the tag wiki for it in private beta, c'mon! (We originally had tags for most major tax entities as it was a very, very common point for questions. Tax is hard!)

Comment: @Amelia I always forget to hover over tags... :) Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get one from HMRC's website. [According to this website](http://www.cliffordtowers.com/what-is-a-form-sa302-and-how-do-you-get-one-from-hmrc/), you need to ask either your accountant (assuming you have one), or get on the phone to HMRC... like you have done.

Hope this helps!